# Flash while changing System Brightness

Tags: android, screen, brightness

My app is a simple "Brightness Changer", that also changes System Brightness (what isn't to easy to implement :D).
I actually set up everything and its working fine... except for one little annoying thing... everytime the brightness changes the screen first "flashes" to the highest brightness (like 100% light) and after a half second or so, it changes to the right brightness.

Example: System Brightness should be 120: 1. Change to 255 (max.), adter half second change to 120.

Here is the code of my two classes. The Dummy class is used to "reset" the (necessary for applying brightness change.)

EDIT: btw. i think the problem is the "lp.screenBrightness = 100/100.0f;" in the dummyactivity. But it wont work without it :/

---

*test.java*

```
public class Test extends Activity
{
    SeekBar seekbar;
    TextView value;
    TextView debug;
    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);
        debug = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview3);
        seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
        {
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int brightness = progress+1;
                double b = brightness/2.55;
                double c = Math.round(b*100)/100;
                int percent = (int) c;
                if (percent==0) {
                    value.setText("Lightlevel: !MIN!");
                }else if (percent==100){
                    value.setText("Lightlevel: !MAX!");
                }else{
                    value.setText("Lightlevel: "+percent+"%");
                }
                debug.setText("int brightness: "+brightness+" / double b:"+b+" / double c: "+c+" / int percent: "+percent);
                Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightness);
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent in = new Intent(Test.this,DummyBrightnessActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 1);

                Intent in = new Intent(Test.this,DummyBrightnessActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }

        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 127);

                Intent in = new Intent(Test.this,DummyBrightnessActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }

        });

        button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 255);

                Intent in = new Intent(Test.this,DummyBrightnessActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

*DummyBrightnessActivity.java*

```
public class DummyBrightnessActivity extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.dummy);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
        lp.screenBrightness = 100/100.0f;
        getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

        Timer timer2 = new Timer();
        timer2.schedule(new TimerTask() {

           public void run() {

              finish();

           }

        }, 500);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for future use.

The problem is really the `lp.screenBrightness = 100/100.0f;`. So i put some variable in the `intent` which has the right value of `brightness`, so i can make it like `lp.screenBrightness = brightness;`.

I know this is kind of short, but if someone ever wants to know more about it,just ask in comment.